# Azure Stream Analytics - convert query output to JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, azure, stream

I have a situation where I have a simple query in an Azure Stream Analytics job:

```
select i1.Asset_Key as Asset_Key
, 0 as Online 
, i1.eventenqueuedutctime as Last_Updated_UTC
, i1.eventenqueuedutctime as Latest_Record_Date
into fsSMSemailAPP
```

It looks like it is returning a typical query result set to a Azure Function (fsSMSemailAPP).

I need to convert the result to json before passing it to the Azure Function.

I have been searching like crazy to find out how to do this, but they either don't seem to be "Selecting Into" or Azure doesn't like any of the sql json commands.

Any idea on how I might be able to get this to work?

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Isn't is so that the function gets the result as json? afaik you do not need to convert it to json yourself

Comment: I've done this many times by things like: `SELECT '{"Asset_Key":"' + i1.Asset_Key + '","OnLine":"0","Last_Updated_UTC":"' + i1.eventenqueuedutctime +.....+'}'` and feeding it into a `coalesce` function. Note that you will need to add `[` and `]` at the beginning and end of the result.

Comment: please see this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017